# Android Studio ¿Por que no puedo iniciar una actividad con un fragment determinado?

Tags: android, android-fragment

**Descripción del problema:**

Tengo una actividad con un botón. Este botón abre otra actividad la cual contiene un fragment. Por algun extraño motivo al tocar el botón, la app. crashea.

**Código JAVA de la actividad que contiene el fragment:**

```
public class categorias extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Fragment fragment_categorias;

    private FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorias);

        fragment_categorias = new fragment_musica();

        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_categorias,fragment_categorias).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
}
```

**Código XML de la actividad que contiene el fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ui.INICIO.RESULTADOS.CATEGORIAS.categorias"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_categorias"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_buscar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Adjunto el error que me lanza Android Studio:**

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class fragment
>       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class fragment
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con respecto a el error, en tu Fragment estas haciendo referencia a un elemento con id `et_buscar` el cual no existe en en layout:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_categorias"
    ...
    ...
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_buscar"
    .../>
```

---

Debes considerar algo importante:

**Si deseas realizar un "reemplazo" de un Fragment, solo puede reemplazar un Fragment agregado dinámicamente". Los Fragments definidos en un layout no pueden ser reemplazados.**

Por lo tanto en lugar de un Fragment:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_categorias"
    ...
    ...
   />
```

usa un `FrameLayout` en el cual no defines un Fragment, pero si puedes realizar reemplazos de Fragmentos dentro de este elemento:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_categorias"
    ...
    ...
   />
```

---

Comment: Mereces el premio al mejor Jorge. Gracias nuevamente!