# ListView No desaparece al cambiar entre fragmentos

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo un problema en Android, estoy haciendo uso de un Bottom navigation, el problema es que cuando cambio entre fragmentos si hace el cambio pero la vista pero la vista del primer fragmento se sigue viendo en los demás aun que se cambie.

Lo que esta dentro del cuadro azul es la vista de primer fragmento que seria el home, y lo que esta en rojo es la vista del segundo fragmento que es el dashboard.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fragmento home tiene un recycler view y cards view.

Este es el XML del MainActivity, aqui esta el nav_host_fragment donde hago la transaccion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" >

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Esta es la manera en la que manejo las transacciones de los fragmentos.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    final Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    final Fragment linksFragment = new DashboardFragment();
    final Fragment quienesSomos = new NotificationsFragment();
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = homeFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations        

        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(myOnNavigationListener);

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, quienesSomos, "quienesSomos").hide(quienesSomos).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, linksFragment, "linksFragment").hide(linksFragment).commit();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, homeFragment, "homeFragment").hide(homeFragment).commit();
        Log.d("ACTIVE","Activo: "+active.getTag());

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener myOnNavigationListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(homeFragment).commit();
                    //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(active.getId(), homeFragment).commit();
                    active = homeFragment;
                    Log.d("ACTIVE","Activo: "+active.getTag());
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_links:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(linksFragment).commit();
                    //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(active.getId(), linksFragment).commit();
                    active = linksFragment;
                    Log.d("ACTIVE","Activo: "+active.getTag());
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_qsomos:
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(quienesSomos).commit();
                    //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(active.getId(), quienesSomos).commit();
                    active = quienesSomos;
                    Log.d("ACTIVE","Activo: "+active.getTag());
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

}
```

No se por que no se quita el primer fragmento que se muestra al cambiar a otros fragmentos.

Este es el XML del fragment home, donde se carga mi ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.seccion.seccion15.ui_session.inicio_session.InicioSessionItemFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_home_item_list" />
```

Y este es donde cargo mi CardView que se mostrara en la lista:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo_post"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Titlo de la noticia"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imagen_noticia"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vista_previa"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Vista previa"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imagen_noticia"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titulo_post" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fecha_post"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Fecha del post"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imagen_noticia"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vista_previa" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagen_noticia"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el xml?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Listo, ya agregue el XML del home, agregue el XML que carga la lista y en donde configuro el card view.

Comment: Donde tienes nav_host_fragment ? que es donde se realiza la transacción de Fragmentos @EnriqueEspinosa

Comment: @Jorgesys ya agregue el XML. el nav_host_fragment esta en el XML de mi MainActivity

Comment: @Jorgesys de hecho, el botton bar navigation que trae por defecto andorid jetpack funciona bien, me refiero a que si le quito el itemListener, si hace el cambio, el problema y el motivo por el cual quiero usar el ItmListener es por que mi fragmento home carga una lista de varios post haciendo uso de retrofit pero cuando cambiaba entre fragmentos la lista volvia a cargar y tardaba en verse de nuevo.

Comment: por eso te preguntaba que era nav_host_fragment  @EnriqueEspinosa , recuerda que solo se pueden reemplazar fragmentos que sean agregados dinámicamente en un Framelayout. Es un caso similar a : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/325454/android-studio-por-que-no-puedo-iniciar-una-actividad-con-un-fragment-determina/325493#325493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pedía agregaras `nav_host_fragment` y veo que es un `Fragment`, **recuerda que si agregas un Fragment este no podrá ser reemplazado mediante una transacción**:

```
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        ...
        ...
        ... />
```

Debes agregar un `Framelayout` para ahí realizar la transacción de Fragmentos:

```
  <Framelayout 
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        ...
        ...
        ... />
```

> Solo se pueden reemplazar aquellos Fragmentos que se han agregado dinámicamicamente
> usando código en un contenedor `Framelayout` mediante `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: Tienes razón, esta fue la solución, muchas gracias :D

Comment: Excelente @EnriqueEspinosa saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré una solución, solamente tuve que cambiar en mi `MainActivity` el fragment por un `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Eso funciono para mi.